# How to train Open NLP without file

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

i have the following code for training Open NLP POS Tagger

```
Trainer(String trainingData, String modelSavePath, String dictionary){

    try {
        dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
                new File(trainingData));

        lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
        ObjectStream<POSSample> sampleStream = new WordTagSampleStream(lineStream);

        POSTaggerFactory fac=new POSTaggerFactory();
        if(dictionary!=null && dictionary.length()>0)
        {
            fac.setDictionary(new Dictionary(new FileInputStream(dictionary)));
        }
        model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), fac);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Failed to read or parse training data, training failed
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lineStream != null) {
            try {
                lineStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Not an issue, training already finished.
                // The exception should be logged and investigated
                // if part of a production system.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this works just fine. Now, is it possible to do the same without involving files? I want to store the training data in a database somewhere. Then i can read it as a stream or chunks and feed it to the trainer. I do not want to create a temp file. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't your sampleStream labelled POS training data in a specific OpenNLP format? Such data is generally hard to come by, and I thought OpenNLP provided this data. Do you want to read from a database because you are storing user annotated POS tagging data in a relational database? I just want to make sure you aren't doing something you don't want to do, normally you would just use the provided file.

Comment: thanks, yes i am getting hand annotated data that is stored in a database

Comment: How is your data stored in the database? Or have you not yet created your schema?

Comment: each data row is of the form

`word1_tag1 word2_tag2 ...`

each row represents a sentence

Comment: so i can read it row by row. i was thinking that conceptually it is similar to reading line by line from a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of passing FileInputStream to a dictionary, you can create your own implementation of InputStream, say DatabaseSourceInputStream and use it instead.